# Read and update xml file with multi level

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I has the XML file as below

```
<Board>
   <Title Text="Overview" />
      <Datas>
         <Data Name="TEST">
            <Parameters>
               <Parameter Name="testing" Value="123" />
               <Parameter Name="testing1" Value="abc" />
            </Parameters>
         </Data>
       </Datas>
  </Board>
```

May I know how I can get the value for testing and testing1?

I use `xmlnodelist = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Parameter")` But can't get the value for testing and testing1.

How I can get the value and update it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `xmlnodelist` variable is `IEnumerable` of some kind so I think you need to use something like `foreach (var item in xmlnodelist) { var name = item.Attribute("Name").Value; var value = item.Attribute("Value").Value;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath. Like this:

```
        XmlNodeList nodes= doc.SelectNodes("Board/Datas/Data/Parameters/Parameter");

        foreach(XmlNode n in nodes)
        {
            string s = n.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Using XPath you can also get nodes with specified attribute value and much more other. Read more about it.